# Correct way to compare dates with Hibernate and Oracle, taking account of daylight savings

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date

I have some Java Hibernate code which is intended to select those rows in an Oracle table where a DATE value (mapped to `startDate`) is at least one hour ago.  To test this, I insert a row directly with a value of Oracle's `sysdate` and then run the code.  Prior to the switch back from BST at the weekend, my code was returning the row, but now zero rows are being returned.  I would have expected this to always return zero rows.  Is my code correct?

```
int cutOffMillis = 1 * 3600 * 1000;
Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -cutOffMillis);
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(DbReport.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.lt("startDate", cal.getTime()));
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this but I am working on legacy code where `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` are used all over the place so I chose to stick with them for consistency.  An answer providing a correct implementation of my intention using the new time classes would be appreciated though.